# Jenkins helm value for passing JAVA_ARGS

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I want to pass some `JAVA_ARGS` in a `jenkins` `kubernetes` instance created using the official helm chart.

Example of such values are:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400
```

etc...

Where in `values.yaml` is the place to do so?

Is this [`javaOpts`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L127) or this [`javaOpts`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L204) the place to do so?

Comment: can you share the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chart uses [Jenkins docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#passing-jvm-parameters) , which says:

> You might need to customize the JVM running Jenkins, typically to pass
>   system properties (list of props) or tweak heap memory settings. Use
>   JAVA_OPTS environment variable for this purpose.

In the chart this is set with [Values.master.javaOpts](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/7461879e1c8aa98148b4fee62961e865b67546ea/stable/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml#L179) from [vaues.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/7461879e1c8aa98148b4fee62961e865b67546ea/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L127)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good amount of time searching for an answer and managed to logic through to a solution that satisfied me. I know this is already answered, but perhaps it will help someone who is looking for this.

The below is an excerpt from my `job.yaml`:

```yml
template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: some-job
        command: ["/somewhere/jre/bin/java", "-Djava.abc.handler.pkgs=util.connection", "-Dcom.abc.properties=/opt/abc/def/deployment.properties", "-cp", "/opt/abc/def/lib/jar/somejava.jar:*:.", "com.abc.def.Deployer"]
```

As you can see, the `-Dargs` need to be specified as a whole unit, with each one separated from the other. I had to have them at the front of the command also, but that may not be required. Afterwards the rest of your command must follow the standard format.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass system properties into the Jenkins controller VM is to use the `controller.containerEnv` value to pass in `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTS`. This variable is not set by default and hence you are safe to provide your own value for it without risking overwriting something important.

Example:

```
controller:
  containerEnv:
    - name: JENKINS_JAVA_OPTS
      value: "-Dcom.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes_credentials_provider.KubernetesCredentialProvider.labelSelector=\"owner=jenkins\""
```